# Jsoup get возвращает только начало страницы

Tags: jsoup, парсер, java

Пробую получить код страницы, используя Jsoup.connect. Вот код:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(тут_нужный_url).get();
```

Но на выходе получаю только начало страницы, т.е. ~60 строк кода, вместо 1000.
MaxBodySize(0) тоже пробовал, не помогает.

С чем это может быть связанно?

------Добавление-----------

Ладно, проблема не понятно в чем. Если не сложно попробуйте выполнить вот этот код. Для него понадобиться библиотека [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Если у вас вывод будет кончаться на < / html> значит проблема у меня. Спасибо.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        Document rawDoc;
        IOException error = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                rawDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").maxBodySize(0).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, rawDoc.toString());
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Может, страница генерится в js или подгружается через ajax.

Comment: Пробовал загрузить главную страницу гугла, такая же проблема.

Comment: Попробуй задать timeout или userAgent.

Comment: Аналогично, самое интересное, неделю назад код работал как надо.

Comment: @nekaneka, на другом девайсе пробовали тестировать?

Comment: Да, 3 разных версии android, запущенные на genymotion. Везде такая же проблема. Я пробовал даже 1.7.3 использовать вместо 1.8.1, результат аналогичен.

Comment: проверил, все работает

Comment: @nekaneka, пробовал на двух реальных устройствах - не сработало. 1.8.1  
Есть предположение, что библиотека просто не может нормально спарсить JS.

Comment: Ой, да ладно, библиотека популярная, куча народа пользуется, и у всех все работает.

Comment: >у всех всё работает  
То есть мы с ТС одни такие?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо того чтобы пихать здоровенную строку в лог, просмотрите ее хотя бы в дебаге. 
Лог ее просто обрезает.